# How to show many view controllers without many xibs

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

Say I want to show 300 words, one in a page, connected by Swipe Gesture or Button. It is definitely feasible to create 300 view controllers in the storyboard and connect them together. But is there a better/faster way to do this without numerous view controllers or xibs? I am a novice here. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Make a property 'text' in a view controller and update that based on something you want

Comment: An easy way to do that is to open a new project as a Page-Based App, read the project comments and modify with your own data. This may not suit your exact needs but should give you a good working example of how one vc can appear to be hundreds.

Comment: Thanks @Marcy But I have 300 words, which may be too long for a page control.

Comment: @Shuichi Not a page control but Apple's project type "Page-Based App" which uses a page view controller. Creating a new project with that project type and then running will show you a demo of something very similar to what you seem to be describing.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand how view controllers work. Think of a view controller as a blank form. You instantiate a view controller, then populate it with unique data. Then When you have different data to display, you create a new blank view controller and give it different data to display.

You don't create a separate XIB or storyboard entry for every instance of a view controller. You create a copy each time you need one. If you have different types of forms you need to display then you might define a different XIB/Storyboard entry for each unique TYPE of view controller, but not for each instance of a type.

To get more specific you've going to have to show the layout of your view controller. (Edit your question to provide more info.)

Comment: Thanks! So what I want to do is I have 300000000 words, starting say from Amy, Bob, etc. You can only see one word in one screen. I want to swipe or click the button to get the next word. Since there are so many words, I don't want to have 300000000 view controllers. How do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UICollectionView` with `scrollDirection = .horizontal`, where each cell represents a **word** view. 
You will need to do some extra work to adjust height and width to make it look like a full screen page on different devices.
So, you have a single view controller, and one, reusable collection view cell for words.

There are many [online tutorials](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9334-uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started), you can use to get a basic collection view up and running, and take it up from there.